# How to prove expression don't relate to value of $k$

Tags: trigonometry

Given: $$\cfrac{1 - \cos (x) + k \sin (x) }{\sin (x) + k + k \cos (x) }$$

How to prove expression don't relate to value of $k$

Solve without using $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x)\cos(x)$

Please help.

Comment: Right now, I can only see this possible by the use of the following identities... $$ 1 - \cos x = 2 \sin^2 (x/2) \\ \sin x = \frac{\sin (2x)}{2\cos x} $$

But since you've mentioned to not use the second identity, it gets difficult. 

May I know what you exactly mean by - "dont relate to value of k" in the title of your question?

Comment: Prove what? The question isn't clear to me. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: It means prove this expression doesn't depend to k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $$F(x,k)=\cfrac{(1 - \cos (x) + k \sin (x) )}{(\sin (x) + k + k \cos (x) )}$$ is not supposed to depend on $k$, just compute $\frac{dF(x,k)}{dk}$ and, after very simple simplification which just uses $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, your will effectively notice that this derivative is exactly equal to $0$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}\frac{1-\cos x+k\sin x}{\sin x+k(1+\cos x)}&=\frac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos x}\cdot \frac{1-\cos x+k\sin x}{\sin x+k(1+\cos x)}\\&=\frac{(1-\cos x)(1-\cos x+k\sin x)}{(1-\cos x)\sin x+k\sin^ 2x}\\&=\frac{(1-\cos x)(1-\cos x+k\sin x)}{\sin x(1-\cos x+k\sin x)}\\&=\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}\end{align}$$

Comment: This is a good one. You can do / prove it by derivating the expression relatively to $k$ and find $0$ as well...

Comment: Yes it's very good answer, thank you mathlove

Comment: @Martigan. I am sorry ! I did not see your comment. It probably came while I was typing.